# Express.js — build new endpoint with an existing internal/local endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, express

New to Express/JS so forgive me if this is obviously impossible. Right now I've got one endpoint that takes a Google API returning lists of government officials and cleaning it up into usable JSON.

```
app.get('/api/officials/:zip', (req, res) => {
  var request = require('request');
  request("https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=" + process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY + "&address=" + req.params.zip, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // body returns a string so make it onto a JSON object
    cleanData = (tons of clean up statements);
    res.send(cleanData);
    }
  })
});
```

Next I have another endpoint where I want to return the results of the above but limit it to a specific entry based on the official's name.

```
app.get('/api/officials/:zip?name=:name', (req, res) => {
  var request = require('request');
  request('/api/officials/' + req.params.zip, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      official = _.find(body, {'name': req.query.name});
      res.send(official);
    }
  })
});
```

I've tried this several ways and just get an `Error: Not Found` on the second endpoint.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `console.log` the `error`'s from your endpoints, whats the full error description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL of your 2nd API endpoint is wrong.

`GET /api/officials/:zip?name=:name`

URL queries are handled differently than URL parameters. When you use `:zip` or `:name` you are saying that there are two `req.params` for this endpoint.

However, what you are trying to do is get the `name` as a URL query instead of a parameter.

Try this instead:

`GET /api/officials/:zip`

URL queries are handled automatically by [express](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

---

In your case, you can handle both the situations in the same API endpoint. Here is how I would do it:

```
app.get('/api/officials/:zip', function(req, res, next) {

  var request = require('request');

  request("https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=" + process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY + "&address=" + req.params.zip, function(error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

      // body returns a string so make it onto a JSON object
      cleanData = "tons of clean up statements"; // do your processing

      if (req.query.name) { // checking if there is a 'name' variable in the req.query object 
        // handling your 2nd API endpoint

        official = _.find(cleanData, { 'name': req.query.name });

        res.send(official);
      } else { // if no 'name' variable is there in the req.query object just send the clean data
        // handling your 1st API endpoint

        res.send(cleanData);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This was super helpful. Thank you! Queries were definitely unclear until now.